# Как сделать столбец в таблице, у которого значение будет точно такое же, как в другом столбце

Tags: mysql, база-данных

В таблице Username два столбца, Login и Name. Как сделать так, чтобы в столбце Name было автоматически такое же значение, как в столбце Login?

Comment: автоматически после какой операции? или во время какой?

Comment: Мой косяк, не уточнил. Во время добавления новой строки в таблицу (сразу после регистрации пользователя).

Comment: А в чём проблема в том же запросе указать два столбца, а не один и туда вставить одинаковые данные?

Comment: почему не выполнить запрос со вставкой значения в оба поля?

Comment: Можно и так, но мне хотелось бы узнать может ли один столбец принимать значение другого без дополнительных запросов.

Comment: trigger before insert

Comment: Так а в чём тут дополнительный запрос состоит, если вы **прямо в том же запросе** заносите данные в **оба поля** а не в одно?

Comment: @Igor наверное всё же after?